# How to get the URL shown at address bar?

Tags: magento-1.9, url

The url at address bar is shown as http://domain/index.php/venues/details

Using `$this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();`

it returns `http://domain/venues/details`
*'index.php' is missing here*

Is anyone aware of any method in magento to get exact same string that is shown in address bar? like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

If there's no such method.. Is it okay to user `$_SERVER` variables in Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER` is a standard PHP global variable, it's fine to use in Magento.  Alternatively you can disable URL_REWRITE support in Magento, which will make it use `index.php` in every URL that's generated, but that's not advisable.